# Center the PopupView? (vaadin)

Tags: java, vaadin

See http://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/structure/popup-view

I can create a popup as seen in the vaadin sampler but how can I center to the middle of the window? I thought I could do .center() like you can do with a vaadin window.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The position of the popup of a PopupView is always relative to the PopupView component. So the only way to center the popup to the middle of the Window is to but the PopupView component itself to the middle of the Window.

Comment: I spent many painful days to realise this! I was being stubborn in the end I just used a window & click listener, easy

Comment: Although maybe I would still argue yes it may be do-able with a lot of hacking away but why bother...